# get rectangle to fill the svg with Raphael and Handdrawn.js

Tags: javascript, css, svg, raphael

So I'm using http://handdrawn.clearcove.ca/ on the following page http://bit.ly/1wOjDNL . As you can see we are currently using images for the hand-drawn borders. We'd like to use the handdrawn.js plugin instead. I've tried doing it on the 'featured-post' but with no good results, it's not as responsive as I would like.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
jQuery('.featured-post').each(function(i){

    var obj = jQuery(this);
    obj.append("<div id='rect"+i+"' class='drawn-rect'></div>");

    var width= obj.outerWidth();
    var height= obj.outerHeight();

    var svg = new Raphael(document.getElementById('rect'+i), "100%", "100%");
    var line= svg.drawnRect(1, 1, width, height, 2);
    line.attr({"stroke":"#000", "stroke-width":10});

});
```

I'd like the SVG element to fill the entire canvas and thus be responsive. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean svg.rect()?  .drawnRect() isn't a raphael thing.

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.rect